# Phpexcel how to delete after upload?

Tags: php, html, database, phpexcel

I've began using phpexcel and have managed to upload an excel file, read it, and insert it into my database but I've noticed that the file I've read was still present. I was under the impression that the file was only temporary. How would I go about deleting the uploaded file?

Comment: Files uploaded via php _are_ of temporary character an the server side, _unless_ you moved (copied) them. No need to delete them, since you should only move (copy) them if you want persistent storage.

Comment: `unlink($file_name);`

Comment: you can delete it using the unlink function of php

Comment: Did you use a move_uploaded_file() before inserting the file in the database: if so, unlink() the file. If you didn't move it, then it should be removed from the temp uploaded folder by PHP itself.... but PHPExcel will not delete any file itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can upload it to an folder then you can apply this you can delete this by using `unlink('filename');` it may help you

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to find out why the files are not deleted automatically, if they are not meant to be stored persistently?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete file with
 `unlink("filename") ;` 
or I advice you to not even download the file.
do not use
 `move_uploaded_files();`
use your temp file to get data.
so no file gonna save and there is nothing to delete.
see this.

```
  $tempXLSFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
     $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($tempXLSFile);
    //your code
```